# How ignore all Google Chrome notifications at same time

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome

[image]

I like get the notification when a new video appear or one of the youTuber is going in a live stream.

The problem is when I watch the video at home and then get to my office the same notifications appear. And you have to close each one. And is very annoying specially after a long weekend. And also do a ding sound and a slow delay for each one.

Ideal scenario would be my work pc know I already watch the video at home and dont pop up the message. But I settle for a way to close all the pop up at once.

Answer (score 1):

Press Win + A on keyboard. this combination opens Notification Center, and press again and it will be closed. And all notification will be dismissed but still visible at Notification Center